# How to get the response in JSON format?

Tags: 7, entities, services

I am using Drupal 7 Services to expose an API. The following is the code I am using to get some of the details and it is giving the response interms of arrays. But I don't want the response to be in Arrays. I want the response in JSON format. What should be the proper solution for this?

The code I am using is:

```
function get_gold_product_items() {

  $query = db_select('node','n');
  $query->Join('field_data_field_gold_price', 'gold_price', 'n.nid = gold_price.entity_id');

  $query->Join('field_data_field_gold_product_type', 'p3', 'n.nid = p3.entity_id');
  $query->Join('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_product_type', 'p3.field_gold_product_type_tid = gold_product_type.tid');

  $query->Join('field_data_field_gold_price_range', 'p4', 'n.nid = p4.entity_id');
  $query->Join('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_price_range', 'p4.field_gold_price_range_tid = gold_price_range.tid');

  $query->Join('field_data_field_gold_gender', 'p6', 'n.nid = p6.entity_id');
  $query->Join('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_gender', 'p6.field_gold_gender_tid = gold_gender.tid');

  $query->Join('field_data_field_gold_wearing_style', 'p8', 'n.nid = p8.entity_id');
  $query->Join('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_wearing_style', 'p8.field_gold_wearing_style_tid = gold_wearing_style.tid');

  $query->Join('field_data_field_gold_color', 'p10', 'n.nid = p10.entity_id');
  $query->Join('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_color', 'p10.field_gold_color_tid = gold_color.tid');

  $query->LeftJoin('field_data_field_gold_design_type', 'p12', 'n.nid = p12.entity_id');
  $query->LeftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_design_type', 'p12.field_gold_design_type_tid = gold_design_type.tid');

  $query->LeftJoin('field_data_field_gold_purity', 'p14', 'n.nid = p14.entity_id');
  $query->LeftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_purity', 'p14.field_gold_purity_tid = gold_purity.tid');

  $query->LeftJoin('field_data_field_gold_ring_size', 'p16', 'n.nid = p16.entity_id');
  $query->LeftJoin('taxonomy_term_data', 'gold_ring_size', 'p16.field_gold_ring_size_tid = gold_ring_size.tid');

  $query->LeftJoin('field_data_field_gold_image', 'p18', 'n.nid = p18.entity_id');
  $query->LeftJoin('file_managed', 'gold_image', 'p18.field_gold_image_fid = gold_image.fid');

  $query->fields('gold_price', array('field_gold_price_value'))
     ->fields('gold_product_type', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_price_range', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_gender', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_wearing_style', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_color', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_design_type', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_purity', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_ring_size', array('name'))
     ->fields('gold_image', array('filename'));

  // ->condition('n.type', $content_type)
  //->condition('gold_product_type.name', $product_type);
  $result = $query->execute();

  while($record = $result->fetchAll()) {
    print_r($record);
  }
```

}

And the response I am getting is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_gold_price_value] => 5678
            [name] => Ring
            [gold_price_range_name] => 5000-10000
            [gold_gender_name] => Male
            [gold_wearing_style_name] => Daily Wear
            [gold_color_name] => Yellow
            [gold_design_type_name] => Classic
            [gold_purity_name] => 22 KT (916)
            [gold_ring_size_name] => 24.5
            [filename] => andaaaaaajvq_2.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_gold_price_value] => 12345
            [name] => Pendant
            [gold_price_range_name] => 10000-15000
            [gold_gender_name] => Female
            [gold_wearing_style_name] => Casual Wear
            [gold_color_name] => Two Tone
            [gold_design_type_name] => 
            [gold_purity_name] => 
            [gold_ring_size_name] => 
            [filename] => n651311f_1.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_gold_price_value] => 150000
            [name] => Bangles
            [gold_price_range_name] => 100000-150000
            [gold_gender_name] => Female
            [gold_wearing_style_name] => Party Wear
            [gold_color_name] => Yellow
            [gold_design_type_name] => Band
            [gold_purity_name] => 22 KT (916)
            [gold_ring_size_name] => 12
            [filename] => different-gold-options-india.jpg
        )

    )
```

How to get the response in JSON format?

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
while($record = $result->fetchAll()) 
{
 print_r($record);
}
```

With this:

```
return $result->fetchAll();
```

And make sure you request the resource with the .json extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir,  I replaced as your suggestion and used the URL as http://brinvents.com/bin/jewels/api/details/retrieve.json, But now I am getting white screen. I don't know why?

Comment: Check your server log for details on the WSOD.

Comment: @param You haven't made the changes (your website is public and I can still the arrays being printed)

Comment: Actually there are many functions are written in my custom module, There this is one of the function I am using.. This is the URL after changing,http://brinvents.com/bin/jewels/api/details/retrieve.json see sir Below two functions are not working means they are giving response as blank..

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what you mean - that URL contains a bunch of printed PHP arrays, it's not blank. If you make the changes I specified in the answer the arrays won't be printed any more, and you'll see the json response.

Comment: I had changed only for one function, now I will check by changing for all the functions..

Comment: After changing I am getting white screen on browser and I checked in Poster there I got 200OK but printing as null, but not getting the actual(required) response in JSON.. Please help me. Thanks for Answers. and this is the URL after changing http://brinvents.com/bin/jewels/api/details/retrieve.json

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you - as long as the code for your resource is correct, and you're using the .json extension, returning an array or object will automatically produce the json response when using the Services module. I've set the same thing up dozens of times and never had a problem. If you're getting a white screen, you may have errors in your server logs which will give you more information. This isn't a debugging service, though, we've gone as far as we can to help you here until you provide more information on the problem.

Comment: Any how thanks for the advice, I will check for the server details and I think I will have a solution soon.